# Running multiple tasks of one DAG in separate machines in Airflow

Tags: redis, celery, airflow

I need to create a dag which looks like this-

[image: airflow dag snapshot]

**print_date** task needs to run from a **server A** and **templated** task needs to run from **server B**. From the documentation it is clear that celery with Redis or RabbitMq will be required. I am using celery along with Redis([puckel/docker-airflow](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow)). I already have airflow running in server B with celery executer.
Do I need to have the same setup in server A as well ??
Also, how will I connect these two tasks in a single dag which are actually present in the different server?
A sample framework for this kind of use case will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do we need to have Redis on both machines

Answer (score 1):

Use Airflow [Queues](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#queues). And when you define your task add a `queue` parameter and assign it to a particular queue.

For example, queue1 would just run all the task on Machine 1 & queue2 would run all tasks on Machine 2.

So you can assign your **task A** to **queue 1**, hence it would run on **Machine 1**
and assign

**task B** to **queue 2**, hence it would run on **Machine 2**

Check documentation at https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#queues

Comment: so i have trigger the dag from both the machines ??

Comment: This does not solve the problem. It's just a "bypass". Besides, to work with more than one queue, the queues must be explicitly specified in the task